# SVG dashoffset start angle

Tags: svg

I created simple circular progress bar with SVG, but I have some troubles with making progress bar starting from the top of the circle (clockwise), and not the right side as currently.

Here's the code:
http://www.webpackbin.com/4yxjPQgMb

I will really appreciate if you can provide some guidance on how can I fix this thing. Thank you.

// Edit: 
I managed to do this via CSS, like this:

`{
  transform: rotateZ(-90deg);
  transform-origin: center center;
}`

But still looking how to do this via JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All non-path graphic shapes (like the `<circle>` you are using) have a defined "equivalent path".  This is specified so that dash patterns behave consistently across all SVG renderers.  In the case of a `<circle>` the equivalent path is defined to start at the 3 o'clock position and proceeds clockwise around the circle.

See: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html#CircleElement

There is no way to alter that other than by rotating or otherwise transforming it.  You can do that with CSS as you have done (doesn't currently work in all browsers) or with a `transform` attribute on the `<circle>`.

Comment: Thank you for answer. And yeah.. MS Edge for e.g. can't handle CSS transform on circle element :/ I need to to this some other way.

Comment: Try adding `:transform="'rotate(-90 ' + size + ' ' + size +')'"` to your blue circle.